# How to use preference headers in a library?

Tags: android, xml, preference

I'm able to create preferences for my apps that are sharing code through a library by passing the preferences' XML resource IDs (say R.xml.settings1 in App1 and R.xml.settings2 in App2) to the PreferenceActivity in the lib through the bundle putInt method. In the PreferenceActivity's onCreate method I just load the XML as follows:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(null!=bundle)
    {
        int settingsID = bundle.getInt("SettingsID");
        if(0<settingsID)
            addPreferencesFromResource(settingsID);
    }
}
```

And everything works fine.

Now I'd like to use preference headers in the library as stated in the Android doc:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#PreferenceHeaders

The method loadHeadersFromResource should be called in PreferenceActivity's onBuildHeaders method but as mentioned:

> Note: When using preference headers, your subclass of PreferenceActivity doesn't need to implement the onCreate() method, because the only required task for the activity is to load the headers.

But onBuildHeaders is called long before onCreate therefore I'm unable to pass the preferences' XML resource ID to loadHeadersFromResource with

```
@Override
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target)
{
    loadHeadersFromResource(settingsID, target);
}
```

where settingsID would be the preference headers' resource IDs from App1 or App2 aka R.xml.settings_headers1 in package com.company.app1 or R.xml.settings_headers2 in package com.company.app2 respectively...

Edit:
If I load an empty XML in onBuildHeaders (say R.xml.empty_settings in package com.company.lib) and then load the "real" XML in onCreate method as:

```
List<Header> mTarget = null;

@Override
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target)
{
    mTarget = target;
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.empty_settings, target);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(null!=bundle)
    {
        int settingsID = bundle.getInt("SettingsID");
        if(0<settingsID&&null!=mTarget)
            loadHeadersFromResource(settingsID, mTarget);
    }
}
```

nothing is displayed in the preference activity!

And finally loading a non empty dummy XML in onBuildHeaders and then loading the "real" XML in onCreate method works but displays the useless dummy preferences loaded from the dummy XML as:

```
List<Header> mTarget = null;

@Override
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target)
{
    mTarget = target;
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.dummy_settings, target);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(null!=bundle)
    {
        int settingsID = bundle.getInt("SettingsID");
        if(0<settingsID&&null!=mTarget)
            loadHeadersFromResource(settingsID, mTarget);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to address this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I figured it out!

Since the list of headers is kept as a member variable the trick is to add a single dummy header in onBuildHeaders and to remove it in onCreate before adding the desired headers from the corresponding app as follows:

```
List<Header> mHeaders = null;

@Override
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target)
{
    mHeaders = target;
    // Add a single dummy header
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.dummy_header, target);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Remove dummy header added in onBuildHeaders
    if(null!=mHeaders&&1==mHeaders.size())
        mHeaders.remove(0);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(null!=bundle)
    {
        int headersID = bundle.getInt("HeadersID");
        if(0<headersID&&null!=mHeaders)
            loadHeadersFromResource(headersID, mHeaders);
    }
}
```

Regards.